# No route matches [POST] "/account/edit"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I works fine on my view page:

```
<%

   me = Users.find(session[:id])

%>
<h1>Edit account</h1>
<form action="" method="post">
 Username: <input type="text" name="username" value="<%=me[:username]%>" /> <br />
 E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" value="<%=me[:email]%>" /><br />
 <input type="submit" value="Update" />
</form>
```

But when i submit the forms i get No route matches [POST] "/account/edit"

My controller:

```
class AccountController < ApplicationController
    def edit  
        if  params[:username] 
        @out = "Hey"
    end
 end
end
```

In routes i tried setting this

```
 post "account/edit"
```

it did also work, but then the session does not work when it refresh, so getting this:

```
 Couldn't find Users without an ID
```

Can someone help me

Comment: Do you have an update action method?

Comment: Update action? I don't know what you mean. I only have this controller and view.

Comment: Right...there should also be an update action in your controller. The edit action renders the edit form (HTTP GET). You also need an action method to handle the actual update (HTTP PUT or PATCH depending on which version of Rails you're running).

Comment: Is there a reason you're not scaffolding this using rails g scaffold account with some attributes?  Doing this and looking at what you get from that will help you learn what you need to change to customize this for yourself.  There are a lot of things wrong with the code above and it's probably easier to use the scaffold and build from there rather than just trying to fix this.

Comment: @RichardJordan has a very good point about using the scaffolding until you get a better idea of what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

EDITING old response:

I think that trying to debug what you have here is not getting anywhere.  The key is there are a lot of problems with your code here and it's not clear what else you have in place that this is interacting with.  If you have no other routes set and no other actions in your controller, what is the POST interacting with?  Where is a create (or similar) action finding the User to get the user ID for which it's creating an account?

I think you need to run the scaffolding as a starting point

```
rails g scaffold account attr1:type attr2:type etc.
```

This will give you something solid you can look at, customize and learn from.  I encourage you to keep trying - it's clear you are wanting to learn.  Good luck with that! :-)

Comment: I works when i am NOT posting it. And i don't says "Id=1", it gets the session id....